# How to make imported/aliased names in AppController available to all controllers?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to add `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry` in AppController to it can be used in all controllers, so there is no need to add it in each one. Is it possible?

i've tried this

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry; <------ want to add this

class AppController extends Controller
{        
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('ConfigsComp');
    }
}
```

But i get this error:

> Error: Class 'App\Controller\Admin\TableRegistry' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No, that's not how importing works, this is a per-file functionality, ie you need to put them in the file where you want to us them.

**[http://php.net/manual/...importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope)**

I'd suggest to use a proper IDE that auto-adds import statements in case you're having a hard time with adding them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification