# CakePHP 3 : global variable to use everywhere

Tags: cakephp, global-variables, cakephp-3.x

I'm working in CakePHP 3 project and want to create global variable to store some information that can be used throughout the application.

I have to store Company information like Name, slogan, description etc and also some links like, I'm using a subdomain out of the main application to store media files like `http://media.website.com` and application is at `http://website.com`. Now I want to store `http://media.website.com` in a global variable so that I can use it anywhere in my application just like `WWW_ROOT`.

For this I tried using `Configure::write('mediaLink', 'http://media.website.com');` and tried to use it in view as `<img src="<?= Configure::read('mediaLink') . DS . 'files' . DS . 'image.jpg'">` but it gives error as `Class Configure is not found`. I tried adding `use Cake\Core\Configure;` to the controller but it gives same error.

Comment: `use` (import) statements work on a [**per file basis**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443159/cakephp-3-include-use-cake-orm-tableregistry-in-appcontroller-to-be-available/32443678#32443678). You may want to re-read: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762119/cakephp-3-define-global-contant-variable**

Comment: Don't use a constant. At some point you're going to find/need to _not_ use the constant and then you need to rewrite the code. The typical first-time that happens is when adding unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a seperate file, say `constants.php`

Define your global constants and `Configure` here.
Don't forget to add this on top of file
  `use Cake\Core\Configure;`

and include this file in your `bootstrap.php` by writing `require __DIR__ . DS.'constants.php';`

**Update** :- put the file `constants.php` in the `application-root-folder\config`.

Comment: `and Configure here` - the right place for that is the app.php or bootstrap.php file.

Comment: @AD7six I think `bootstrap.php` is the right place

Comment: This answer does not say that

Comment: @AD7six Ok, you probably misunderstood, my english, I want to say write `Configure::write('mediaLink', 'http://media.website.com');` in this file

Comment: `Make a seperate file, say constants.php

Define your global constants and Configure here.` This does not say "bootstrap is the right place", I don't think language is a factor.

Comment: @AD7six I'm not getting your point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116059/discussion-between-aipd-tech-and-ad7six).

Comment: @Pradeep Singh, you can improve a little your answer. For example, put the file constants.php in the application-root-folder\config.

Comment: @danilo Updated buddy